# show full or short text of review via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a block on the page that displays a short description of the review.
See layout on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mv87M/)

I want to realize when user clicks on link (tag `a` inside `div` with class `nickname`) then full review shows and vice versa.

How is the best way to do that?

I think to do the following way: when user clicks on the link then send ajax request for full review, if now shows full review then send request again but get only 300 chars, for example. But, for this way I need to send two request.

Comment: Any reason you don't have the whole review on the page, but have the extra text wrapped in a hidden span or div. Then just have the link show everything else?

Comment: @Prescott:I can not imagine how to do it. Can you show a small example or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing your code: http://jsfiddle.net/sessa/mv87M/20/

Make sure to hide the span.more-text via CSS.  Use of toggle is perfect here.

```
$('.nickname').click(function() {
       $(this).next('.text').find('.more-text').toggle();
       $(this).next('.text').find('.ellipses').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").click(function(){
    if($(".new",this).is(":visible"))
    $(".new",this).hide();
    else
            $(".new",this).show();
});
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/mv87M/17/show/

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my small blurb of text.....
...................................
...................................


<div id="hiddentext" style="display:none;">
Hidden more text...................
...................................
...................................
</div>
```

Show Full Text

Javascript (using jquery):

```
$("#showmore").click(function () {
     $("#hiddentext").show();
});
```